# Windows 7 Laptop Wifi Doesn't Prompt for Password (Unable to connect to wifi)

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, dell-latitude

```
UPDATED-STATEMENT: 20190317@232000@SUN Post created
UPDATED-STATEMENT: 20190419@091447@FRI Confirmed solution to be "(Forgetting previously connected Wifi Logins)" after testing several different PC's with the same issue.
```

```
Laptop: Dell Latitude Laptop on Windows 7
Router: Linksys Wireless Router - staticip; dhcpdisabled
```

I'm unable to connect to any Wifi using my Laptop on Windows 7. **Device Manager** shows no signs of missing drivers as there's no yellow caution symbol. For the wifi that does work on other devices doesn't work with the my Windows 7 Laptop. What I experience is seeing the SSID to connect to but stays stuck on loading bar without prompting for password. This is the same laptop that has not connected to this SSID ever before so password isn't previously saved. Other devices can connect to the router and the troubled laptop can connect to other wifi's besides the router i'm using.

What does it mean when Wifi doesn't prompt you for password on an SSID that has security/password?

### PROBLEM

- Dell Latitude Laptop on Windows 7 doesn't connect to wifi and isn't being prompted for password

  - Devicemanager shows no missing drivers
  - Localareaconnection is set to dhcp for ipv4
- DHCP is disabled on the Linksys Wireless Router

### SOLUTION

- You have to forget the once joined SSID's password to re-connect with a password prompt to continue.

  - Instructions to forget wifi password is tedious and very well hidden, so i'm unable to provide clear instructions

#### NOTE

- SSID has a password assigned via security wpa2 personal and works on other devices such as other laptops and phones.
- Laptop Network Card is able to show list of broadcasted SSID's so it's not a wifi-lock issue or function-key-wifidisabled issue either
- WPA Algorithm isn't listed for the router i'm using

Comment: I have 2 laptops with same symptoms, the wireless radio does not power up when booting, the only solution I have found is to restart until I get the wireless radio indicator light to glow. Not all laptops have indicator lights. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: It's not a Wifi-lock issue as this laptop doesn't have a hardware based one. The keyboard Function key is set to have it enabled that's how i'm even able to see the SSID broadcast list to choose from. It's just my particular Wifi dosen't ask for password and therefore isn't able to continue any further.